# enabling rpc only with certain commands

Tags: bitcoind, miner-configuration, diablominer

I want to set up a bitcoind server with multiple diablo instances on systems i have access to. other people also have access to these machines, and my password for bitcoind will have to be input to the diablo instances. this means someone could have access to my bitcoind password and so also my bitcoins stored there. is there any way i can enable only the rpc commands in bitcoind to allow mining efforts? or to allow mining efforts without the password?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would advise not giving anyone direct access to your bitcoind instance. You need either a queue/ or an API in between that can throttle requests/ and manage ACL's as you require.